# Hint on solving Riccati differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hint on solving the following ODE

$$y' + a x^{2} y + x y^{2} = a$$

where $a$ is a real number.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%2Bax%5E2y%2Bxy%5E2%3Da

Answer (score 1):

Riccati equations arise as  natural equation solutions.

Please refer to page 26 LP Eisenhart and page 37 DJ Struik and look them through.

Cross Ratios of four particular integrals is constant.

Comment: let me Know title of books, please.

Comment: In differential geometry they are most well known. If after your own search which will be certainly fruitful you do not succeed please ping me. Also consult books on Relativity theory and Tensors analysis.

Comment: Is your mean "An introduction to differential geometry with use of tensor calculus" by  LP Eisenhart  and "Lectures on Classical Differential Geometry" by DJ Struik ?

Comment: Yes for both, Eisenhart has another book with title "Riemannian geometry". If out of print, the one you quote should also perhaps do. Also look up the classical author :AR Forsyth, Differential geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $a\neq0$ for the key case:

Hint:

Approach $1$:

Let $y=\dfrac{u'}{xu}$ ,

Then $y'=\dfrac{u''}{xu}-\dfrac{u'}{x^2u}-\dfrac{(u')^2}{xu^2}$

$\therefore\dfrac{u''}{xu}-\dfrac{u'}{x^2u}-\dfrac{(u')^2}{xu^2}+\dfrac{axu'}{u}+\dfrac{(u')^2}{xu^2}=a$

$\dfrac{u''}{xu}-\dfrac{u'}{x^2u}+\dfrac{axu'}{u}-a=0$

$xu''+(ax^3-1)u'-ax^2u=0$

We can make comparison with another approach, as all Riccati equations with dependent variable $y$ have an interesting property that the substitution $y=\dfrac{1}{u}$ will brings the Riccati equations to the Riccati equations again, but the coefficients are rearranged.

Approach $2$:

Let $y=\dfrac{1}{u}$ ,

Then $y'=-\dfrac{u'}{u^2}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{u'}{u^2}+\dfrac{ax^2}{u}+\dfrac{x}{u^2}=a$

$u'+au^2-ax^2u-x=0$

Let $u=\dfrac{v'}{av}$ ,

Then $u'=\dfrac{v''}{av}-\dfrac{(v')^2}{av^2}$

$\therefore\dfrac{v''}{av}-\dfrac{(v')^2}{av^2}+\dfrac{(v')^2}{av^2}-\dfrac{x^2v'}{v}-x=0$

$\dfrac{v''}{av}-\dfrac{x^2v'}{v}-x=0$

$v''-ax^2v'-axv=0$